# Conventions on naming Eclipse projects?

Tags: eclipse, naming-conventions

Are there any naming conventions (or at least suggestions) on how to name an Eclipse project?
Is using acronyms a good idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Eclipse Foundation itself have [suggestions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Naming_Conventions#Eclipse_Workspace_Projects). Instead `org.eclipse....`user your own domain!

**Edit**:
I have no documented best practices. But I use as project name the name of the main package in the project. Ancronyms are OK if you have long names. Example:

```
Java Developement Tools -> JDT
```

For additional improvements see the [Eclipse Project Name Policy](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Development_Resources/HOWTO/Project_Naming_Policy)!

Comment: I'm not meaning package naming conventions.

Comment: @Helper The linked section talks about project names: "When Eclipse is being used to develop plug-ins for the Eclipse project, the name of the Eclipse workspace project should match the name of the plug-in. For example, org.eclipse.core.runtime plug-in is developed in an Eclipse workspace project named org.eclipse.core.runtime."

Comment: @Fabian Steeg: I added that link after the comment of Helper Method!